# Connect pivot table with multiple tables in Eloquent

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, orm

I have this model:

```
User:
id (int)
name (varchar)

Role:
id int
name (varchar)

User_Role
id (int)
id_role (int)
id_user (int)
id_company (int)
```

What I need using Eloquent (Laravel 7), is to query user_role with the id_company:

This is my relationship into User model

```
public function rol() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\Role','user_role','id_user','id_role');
}
```

This is my relationship into Role model:

```
function user() {
   return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\User','user_role','id_role','id_user');
}
```

Is it possible to query the pivot table like this:

```
$user->rol->where(["id_company" => $params["id_company"]])->toArray();
```

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of users that have roles matching that `id_company` field?

Comment: Hi! I am trying to get the role that match that user and the `id_company`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first include the pivot table columns in the relationship:

```
public function roles() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\Role','user_role','id_user','id_role')
              ->withPivot('id_company');
}
```

Then you can query on the pivot table column:

```
$user->roles()->wherePivot('id_company', $params["id_company"])
              ->get()
              ->toArray();
```